# Raycast not working on touchscreen (Android tablet/phone)

Tags: android, unity, raycasting, touch

I have a raycast that works in the unity editor but not when I build it for Android( tablet or phone, neither work). The code I'm using is as follows:

```
public class DirectionalTilePlacing : MonoBehaviour {

public LayerMask levelLayer;
private int tileType;
public int Tiletype
    {
        get { return tileType; }
    set
    {
        tileType = value;
    }
    }
RaycastHit hit;
Vector2I placePosition;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, levelLayer))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Replaceable")
        {

            transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Floor(hit.point.x) + 0.5f, Mathf.Floor(hit.point.y), Mathf.Floor(hit.point.z) + 0.5f);
            GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, levelLayer))
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Replaceable")
            {
                placePosition = new Vector2I((int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.z);
                EditorManager.map.SetEmpty(placePosition);
                EditorManager.map.BrushTile(EditorManager.map.TypeToObject((Tile.tileType)tileType), placePosition, (Tile.tileType)tileType);
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
    }

}
```

}

Everything up until any Physics.Raycast line works. The idea is that there is a ray casted from the position your finger is at when touching the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple. I found out that none of the objects in question had a collider whatsoever. So added colliders and everything works now. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Input.getMouseButton try this

if you want to detect only one screen touch use this:

```
 if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, levelLayer))
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Replaceable")
        {
            placePosition = new Vector2I((int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.z);
            EditorManager.map.SetEmpty(placePosition);
            EditorManager.map.BrushTile(EditorManager.map.TypeToObject((Tile.tileType)tileType), placePosition, (Tile.tileType)tileType);
            GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
}
```

but if you want to detect all touches use this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {

    if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
         ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, levelLayer))
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Replaceable")
        {
            placePosition = new Vector2I((int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.z);
            EditorManager.map.SetEmpty(placePosition);
            EditorManager.map.BrushTile(EditorManager.map.TypeToObject((Tile.tileType)tileType), placePosition, (Tile.tileType)tileType);
            GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This works the same way mouse input works. Because when you build it for Android Unity converts mouse input to touch input.